# Difference between .hbs and .hjs in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I don't understand the different between .hjs and .hbs. After some dumb experiments, I found out that .hjs is for pure templates and .hbs is for partials.

Could someone point me point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I dont use hbs in my current projects - they are all in wp that uses php and simple html+css - but recently I found this project, ghost.org, and the template files use only HBS.

I think it makes sense that they are uses to templates.